# Confused about payment for real goods through iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am making a restaurant application in which the user can select any food item and our application needs to charge  as per the food item selected. But I am confused as we cannot use INApp for this so what should be the best option for my application keeping in mind with apple document.And finally i dont want to use paypal also.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not allow you to use their In App Purchase API to pay for real-world goods.

Your only option is to use a web view to display a web-based payment system of your choosing, or use another payment API such as Paypal (which you have already expressed you don't want to use).

Comment: If i make payment by opening webview in my application then is that fair play with apple documentation means it wouldnt get rejected by apple na ..